# Error message "undefined symbol: mysql_get_client_info" in C

Tags: mysql, c

I am attempting to learn C!

I have looked at numerous documentation and tutorials online and I am attempting to get some simple output of the MySQL client version as per [this website](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/).

I do not understand however what is causing the below error message that I am receiving:

> undefined symbol: mysql_get_client_info

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

DLLFUNC int MOD_LOAD(m_sql)(int module_load)
{
        sendto_ops("MySQL client version: %s", mysql_get_client_info());
        return MOD_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It's the 5th line in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

When do you get this message?  Are you linking with the MySQL library?